# Omniauth-Twitter/Devise error: "Could not authenticate you from Twitter because "Invalid credentials""

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter, devise, omniauth

I'm using the omniauth-twitter gem with devise, and followed the [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/235-devise-and-omniauth-revised) on how to implement it.

Everything seems to work fine - I can click on the sign_up with twitter link, it redirects me to twitter, I click on 'log in' and then it redirects me back BUT with the error message "Could not authenticate you from Twitter because "Invalid credentials".

I'm at a total loss and the obvious solutions like mixing up the position of my consumer and secret key I have checked, and they're all fine.

I tried reading the several different variations on SO regarding omniauth-devise and none of them helped.

Here's the relevant code:

```
 devise_scope :user do
    get 'sign_up', to: 'members#new', controllers: {registrations: "members"}
    get 'partners/sign_up', to: 'content_partners#new', controllers: {registrations: "content_partners"}
  end
  devise_for :users, controllers: {omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks"}
```

From the config/initializers/device file:

```
 require "omniauth-twitter"
   config.omniauth :twitter, 'CONSUMER_KEY', 'CONSUMER_SECRET'
```

My gemfile:

```
gem "omniauth", "~> 1.1.1"
gem "omniauth-twitter", "~> 0.0.14"
```

My controller:

```
class OmniauthCallbacksController < Devise::OmniauthCallbacksController
  def all
    user = User.from_omniauth(request.env["omniauth.auth"])
    if user.persisted?
      flash.notice = "Signed in!"
      sign_in_and_redirect user
    else
      session["devise.user_attributes"] = user.attributes
      redirect_to sign_up_path
    end
  end
  alias_method :twitter, :all
end
```

My user model:

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
    end
  end

  def self.new_with_session(params, session)
    if session["devise.user_attributes"]
      new(session["devise.user_attributes"], without_protection: true) do |user|
        user.attributes = params
        user.valid?
      end
    else
      super
    end
  end
```

The link in my sign_up view file:

```
<%= link_to "or Sign up with Twitter", user_omniauth_authorize_path(:twitter) %>
```

Finally, here is what I'm getting from the logger:

```
Started GET "/users/auth/twitter" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-11 15:54:01 +0000
(twitter) Callback phase initiated.


Started GET "/users/auth/twitter/callback?oauth_token=****blanked****&oauth_verifier=****blanked****" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-12-11 15:54:03 +0000
Processing by OmniauthCallbacksController#twitter as HTML
  Parameters: {"oauth_token"=>"****blanked****", "oauth_verifier"=>"****blanked****"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."provider" = 'twitter' AND "users"."uid" = '803184474' LIMIT 1
   (0.1ms)  BEGIN
  User Exists (0.4ms)  SELECT 1 AS one FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" IS NULL LIMIT 1
   (0.2ms)  ROLLBACK
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/sign_up
Completed 302 Found in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
```

Could anyone help me with this?!

Comment: Do you have an omniauth.rb file?

Comment: No, but actually I have just managed to get it working.  The issue was that I was trying to sign up as an existing user, so once I deleted myself, I could then sign up/in with twitter as expected.  Now I'm trying to figure out how to override the requirement to provide an email address when signing up with twitter!

Comment: If you check devise's source code, you'll notice that it has this method called [email_required?](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/validatable.rb#L57). Just add that method to your user model like you added the `password_required?` method.

Comment: Thanks.  I have tried that, I've tried 'def email_required? false  end' and also 'def email_required? super && provider.blank? end' but neither are having any effect.

Comment: You should close this question and ask another one if you have some other problem.